# How do I use compiler intrinsic __fmul_?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, cuda, intrinsics

I am writing a massively parallel GPU application using CUDA. I have been optimizing it by hand. I received a 20% performance increase with `__fdividef_(x, y)`, and according to *The Cuda C Programming Guide (section C.2.1)*, using similar functions for multiplication and adding is also beneficial.

The function is stated as this: `__fmul_[rn,rz,ru,rd](x,y)`.

`__fdividef(x,y)` was not stated with the arguments in brackets. I was wondering, what are those brackets?

If I run the simple code:

```
int t = __fmul_(5,4);
```

I get a compiler error about how `__fmul_` is undefined. I have the CUDA runtime included, so I don't think it is a setup thing; rather it is something to do with those square brackets. How do I correctly use this function? Thank you.

EDIT: I should clarify, the compiler is the CUDA-compiler NVCC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify rounding mode with `ru` (rounding up) or `rd` (rounding down). There is no function `__fmul_` but available function signatures are `__fmul_rd` or `__fmul_ru`.

Comment: If I am using this to replace the usual '*' (asterisk syntax), and I want to retain all precision (single precision floats), what should I specify?

Comment: This functions are IEEE-compliant.

Comment: The brackets indicate a list from which one must chose one item. The actual intrinsics are called __fmul_rn(), __fmul_rz(), __fmul_ru(), and __fmul_rd(). To replace the normal multiplication operator for single-precision computation, you would want to use __fmul_rn(). That is a multiplication with rounding to "nearest of even", which is what the multiplication operator maps to. To replace a double-precision multiplication operator, you would want to use __dmul_rn() instead. The other IEEE rounding modes are supported for special purposes, for example interval arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

[CUDA Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#intrinsic-functions) explains the suffixes:

- `_rd`: round down.
- `_rn`: round to nearest even.
- `_ru`: round up.
- `_rz`: round towards zero.

See [CUDA's Single Precision Intrinsics documentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SINGLE.html) for details on these functions.